# Choose Snapping Point?

Tags: modeling, vertices, workflow, snapping

I have a building block that has a cube for the ceiling, walls, and floor. It also has a blast door that overlaps the walls to fit into the next building block.

The problem is that when I align the building blocks together, I want to align the edges of the walls together, using snapping.  When I try to do so, however, it snaps using the edge of the projecting blast door to the edge of the opposite wall, instead of wall-to-wall. I'm snapping from corner to corner. I made an example image:

[image]

It would be nice if I could still use snapping, like temporarily choose a specific vertex to use as a snap. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of these rooms and doors?

Comment: sure thing will do.

Comment: Is it edge center to edge center?

Comment: hold on. I'll elaborate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the workflow I've found for doing this repetitively in Object mode.
The setup:

- Pivot set to '3D Cursor'
- Snap-magnet: 'Off'
- Snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Center'. Because of the 'Pivot' setting, 'Center'  refers to the location of the 3D Cursor at the start of the move.
- (The active tool is 'Tweak'.. it always is, for me)

The moves, for each snap:

- Shift-Right  drag the cursor. Once you're in charge of the cursor, you can release the Shift.
- Still Right-dragging, hold Ctrl to snap the cursor to the desired 'From' vertex. You have now established the snap 'From' point.
- Now Left-drag the 'From' object to the 'To' object, with Ctrl, hovering over the target 'To' vertex. The 'From' point will snap to it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not used to handling the 3d cursor like that, but I should: its quicker than the empty trick and lead to similar results.

Comment: @lemon Just for once, I think this way is better :). I still wish the cursor was a more complete tool. If you set the cursor-tool orientation to 'Geometry', Shift-S snapping should respect that straight away. ATM, you have to drag the cursor across a surface to get it to adopt the face orientation which screws the snap, so you have to do it again.

Comment: Robin, yes this way is better (you should remove the "for once"). Also you may complete your answer with the door alignment maybe?

Comment: @lemon Ahh I see! You meant rotations? Your way may reduce the moves for those?

Comment: Robin, no, I was talking about the green arrow (the place for the door) in RBlong2us question.

Comment: I gotta say, I like how you did this!  I've never had to change the Snap To setting before, but that's not a bad thing to have to do.  Thanks a lot for helping me with this!  Awesome quick way to do it!

Answer (score 4):

Not really short, but...

You want to snap A on B.

**First step**

Set the snapping to *"edge center"* and snap with *"active"*.

Add an empty and bring it on the side of A.

Select A and the empty with empty as active.

Snap them 2 on the side of B: that aligns the rooms.

[image]

**Second step**

Move the empty on top of the door part.

Set snapping to *"edge perpendicular"*.

Move A and the empty (active) to the top of B: that aligns the door.

[image]

Comment: actually, the first step completes my question.  The blast door is supposed to overlap into the next building block.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

New in **Blender 4!** - use the 'b' key mid-move.

To Snap the corner of Box A onto Box B

( Assuming "Snap To" includes Vertex )

- Select Box A and press [g] to begin a move.
- press [b]
- click on the corner you want to use as a snapping point.
- now resume moving Box A and you'll be able to snap that corner to Box B

Note "Snap" is automatically enabled when you press 'b' in this way.
You can also select edges etc, not just vertices.

Another handy V4 feature: hold Alt and use middle mouse to rotate your view mid-move.